# Android ACTION_PICK images ~ Where are they?

Tags: android, image

I click on an ImageView and can now successfully change the image by selecting one from... well... somewhere I guess? Using Genymotion and ADM I would hope to drag and drop some relevant images for testing.

```
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

It's a simple question really, I want to upload using Android Device Monitor some images to choose from.

So where do I upload them?

Thank you for your time.
Always learning!

Comment: Someone downvoted my question. I don't know why. I thought this question was really simple, yet no one knows so far. I'll research some more and post the answer when I find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACTION_PICK used to select a file from provided Uri

If you want to select from anywhere, I recommend ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Comment: So I did try, yet I still don't know where to upload my test images using the ADM

Answer (score 0):

It picks images from your Gallery as a whole.All your recent images

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out using the Android Device Manager you can upload them almost anywhere and access them. My inexperience with Android made me miss a rather simple UI feature...the top left file system navigator. Guess it was a bit too late to program last night.

[image]